# String conversion of decimal in JavaScript (decimal to string)

Tags: javascript

Can you guys explain why `string` conversion of 65.00 returns 65 instead of 65.00?

```
  var dec_1 = 65.01;
  var dec_2 = 65.00;
  var n1 = String(dec_1);  // returns 65.01
  var n2 = String(dec_2);  // returns 65
```

Comment: I'm sure there's a dupetarget for the sort-of-implied "how" part of this question, but I've never seen the "why" part of it before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that's how `Number.prototype.toString` is specified to work. It only includes as many places after the decimal as it needs to differentiate the number from another *representable* number.¹

If you want a fixed number of decimal places, use `toFixed`:

```js
var dec_1 = 65.01;
var dec_2 = 65.00;
var n1 = dec_1.toFixed(2); // "65.01"
var n2 = dec_2.toFixed(2); // "65.00"
console.log(n1);
console.log(n2);
```

---

¹ This is true even if the actual number value, if printed in full, would have had more non-zero digits on it. Full details in [the specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-tostring), it's actually quite an involved process which is the subject of significant academic research.

For example, consider the number `1.1`:

```js
console.log(String(1.1)); // "1.1"
```

Simple enough, right? Except that `1.1` can't be represented **exactly** in the [IEEE-754 double-precision floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) number type that JavaScript uses. When you use `1.1` in your code, the number value that creates is *ever so slightly higher* than 1.1:

```js
console.log((1.1).toFixed(52)); // "1.1000000000000000888178419700125232338905334472656250"
```

The reason the default `toString` doesn't include those digits is that they aren't important; both `1.1` and `1.1000000000000000888178419700125232338905334472656250` end up being the same bit pattern in the number. So those extra digits aren't necessary to differentiate the number from the next *representable* number. So they're left off.

You can see that here:

```js
console.log(1.1 === 1.1000000000000000888178419700125232338905334472656250); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

Use toFixed:

```
var n2 = dec_2.toFixed(2)
```

Comment: The OP was asking how to add 2 decimal digits to a whole number in the output. The toFixed() method is a built-in method of numeric data types that converts the number into a string with provided dumber of digits after the decimal point (see [link] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).Hence using this method will display the number 65 as "65.00" and not as "65" - which was the original question.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you also included the explanation in the answer itself.